# Make sure these files are loaded before it run any other script

Tags: javascript, load

Hi I have a stylesheet and JavaScript function which loads in all the required files for that template.

However I am having a bit of an issue due to when the other script tags run within the template file (plan js code) it does not wait for the required files to load.

So what you have happening is scripts not recognizing functions and other JS functions.

JS Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var uid = '{$smarty.session.ipet_user}';

    function stylesheet(url) {
            var s = document.createElement('link');
            s.rel = 'stylesheet';
            s.async = false;
            s.href = url;
            var x = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            x.appendChild(s);
        }

        function script(url) {
            var s = document.createElement('script');
            s.type = 'text/javascript';
            s.async = true;
            s.src = url;
            var x = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            x.appendChild(s);
        }


         (function () {            
                script('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js');
                script('https://apis.google.com/js/api:client.js');
                script('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyBk99v0F4qkmvxifqOD48YktK-QO-3kopI');
                script('./templates/main/user-theme/javascript/google.js');
                script('plugins/getmdlselect/getmdl-select.min.js');
                script('./templates/main/user-theme/javascript/facebook.js');
                script('./templates/main/user-theme/javascript/newprofile.js');
                script('./templates/main/javascript/zipcode.js');

                stylesheet('https://opensource.keycdn.com/fontawesome/4.7.0/font-awesome.min.css');
                stylesheet('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
                stylesheet('https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons');
                stylesheet('./templates/main/user-theme/tpl-files/material.act.css');
                stylesheet('plugins/dropzone/dropzone.css');
                stylesheet('plugins/stepper/stepper.min.css');
                stylesheet('./templates/main/user-theme/tpl-files/style.css');
                stylesheet('./templates/main/style/newprofile.css');
                stylesheet('plugins/getmdlselect/getmdl-select.min.css');       



         })();
 </script>
```

Comment: You need to chain the scripts into a callback, rather than simply calling the function multiple times. I'd recommend structuring your various scripts into an array, then cycling through that array calling `script([array_index])`, and then calling `script([array_index + 1])` as the callback for script insertion.

Comment: you'll need to listen to the `load` events

Comment: script tag on modern browsers support the onload callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `load` event of `<script>` and `<link>` element, `Promise` constructor and `Promise.all()` to return a resolved `Promise` once all requested resources have loaded by passing an array of URL's to request to `Array.prototype.map()` where each array of URL's is concatenated to a single array where each function is called which `return`s a `Promise`

```
    function stylesheet_(url) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var s = document.createElement('link');
        s.rel = 'stylesheet';
        // s.async = false;
        s.href = url;
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        x.appendChild(s);
        s.onload = resolve;
        s.onerror = reject;
      })
    }

    function script(url) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        s.async = true;
        s.src = url;
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        x.appendChild(s);
        s.onload = resolve;
        s.onerror = reject
      })
    }

    function loadStylesAndScripts(styleList = Array(), scriptList = Array()) {
      return Promise.all(
        styleList.map(stylesheet_)
        .concat(scriptList.map(script))
      )
    }

    let requests = loadStylesAndScripts();
    requests.then(function() {
      console.log("styles and scripts loaded")
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log("an error occurred requesting styles and scripts")
    })
```